# Cleaning small artefacts from polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, v.clean

With some success, I've been generalising and cleaning Ordnance Survey OpenData VectorMap District woodland polygon shapefiles to make them fit for mid-scale mapping.

However, the resulting shapefiles contain small 'tails' that I wish to eliminate. I've put black dots next to some of these on the attached picture. The problem is that the 'tails' are actually part of the larger polygons, so I can't get rid of them using (for example) GRASS v.clean rmarea.

Can anyone help with this problem?

A sample shapefile (cleaned.shp) is included in this [zip archive](http://confound.me.uk/maps/Examples.zip).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try bufferring the polygons by -15m, dissolve, and buffer by a 15m.